# retrieve strategy.netprofit, strategy.closedtrades as a result of changing parameter in loop/iteration (FOR)

Tags: parameters, pine-script, back-testing

I am backtesting my strategy with parameter/variable which influences the result of the strategy. I would like to display how strategy.netprofit and strategy.closedtrades changes while the parameter/variable is changed. As the result I would like to display a table in pineScript where the strategy.netprofit, strategy.closedtrades and the different values of the variable (per) is displayed. The changing variable is by the FOR loop.  The problem I am facing is that while the For is changing the variable (per) the values (strategy.netprofit and strategy.closedtrades) assigned to table are not changing and remain the same independently to the variations of the (per) induced by For loop.Snapshot of the resulting table below.[Table with NetProfit, Total Closed Trades, and changing per variable for which the NetProfi, total Closed Trades should change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFKx6.png)

```
//@version=5
strategy('MOST with Table', shorttitle='MOST with Table', overlay=true, initial_capital=100000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, 
         default_qty_value=100, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, pyramiding=0, commission_value=0.2, 
         max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500, max_boxes_count=500, calc_on_every_tick=true)



var rodzajeAlertow = "=====Rodzaje dostepnych alertów====="
GL_odYear = input.int(2019,"od Rok", 1950, tooltip = "Rok od kiedy zaczynamy obliczenia",  inline="odrok", group = rodzajeAlertow)
GL_odMonth = input.int(01, "Miesiąc", 1,12, tooltip = "Miesiąc od którego zaczynamy obliczenia", inline="odrok", group = rodzajeAlertow)
GL_odDay = input.int(03, "Dzień",1,31, tooltip = "dzień miesiąca od którego zaczynamy obliczenia", inline="odrok", group = rodzajeAlertow)
GL_doYear = input.int(2112,"do Rok", 1950, tooltip = "Rok do kiedy  obliczenia",  inline="dorok", group = rodzajeAlertow)
GL_doMonth = input.int(01, "Miesiąc", 1,12, tooltip = "Miesiąc do którego  obliczenia", inline="dorok", group = rodzajeAlertow)
GL_doDay = input.int(01, "Dzień",1,31, tooltip = "dzień miesiąca do którego  obliczenia", inline="dorok", group = rodzajeAlertow)


// === okono czasowe do obliczeń strategii ===
start     = timestamp(GL_odYear, GL_odMonth , GL_odDay, 00, 00)            // backtest start  window
finish    = timestamp(GL_doYear, GL_doMonth, GL_doDay, 23, 59)            // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false     

var netProfitArray = array.new_float(40)
var Trail1Array = array.new_float(40)
var  totalTradesArray = array.new_int(40)
var  profitableTradesArray = array.new_int(40)
var  profitFactorArray = array.new_float(40)
var iteracjaArray = array.new_int(40)

var float netProfit = na
var int totalTrades = 0
var int profitableTrades = 0
var float profitFactor = na

src =  close 

mova = 'KAMA'


//Kaufman Moving Average Adaptive (KAMA)

float xvnoise = na
float nfastend = na
float nslowend = na
float nsignal = na
float nnoise = na
float nefratio = na
float nsmooth = na
float s15 = na


float Trail1 =na 

// Tworzenie tabeli
var table = table.new(position.top_right,  6,  500, color.orange, border_width = 1)

table.cell(table_id = table, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Net Profit")
table.cell(table_id = table, column = 1, row = 0, text = "Total Closed Trades")
table.cell(table_id = table, column = 2, row = 0, text = "Percent Profitable")
table.cell(table_id = table, column = 3, row = 0, text = "Profit Factor")
table.cell(table_id = table, column = 4, row = 0, text = "MA Type")
table.cell(table_id = table, column = 5, row = 0, text = "per")

for per =3 to 37
    

    if mova == 'KAMA'
        xvnoise := math.abs(src - src[1])
        nfastend := 0.666
        nslowend := 0.0645
        nsignal := math.abs(src - src[per])
        nnoise := math.sum(xvnoise, per)
        nefratio := nnoise != 0 ? nsignal / nnoise : 0
        nsmooth := math.pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2)
        s15 := 0.0
        s15 := nz(s15[1]) + nsmooth * (src - nz(s15[1]))
        Trail1 := s15
    
    
    AF2 = input.float(defval=.47, title='Percent', minval=0.1) / 100
    SL2 = Trail1 * AF2  // Stop Loss
    Trail2 = 0.0
    iff_1 = Trail1 > nz(Trail2[1], 0) ? Trail1 - SL2 : Trail1 + SL2
    iff_2 = Trail1 < nz(Trail2[1], 0) and Trail1[1] < nz(Trail2[1], 0) ? math.min(nz(Trail2[1], 0), Trail1 + SL2) : iff_1
    Trail2 := Trail1 > nz(Trail2[1], 0) and Trail1[1] > nz(Trail2[1], 0) ? math.max(nz(Trail2[1], 0), Trail1 - SL2) : iff_2


    Buy = ta.crossover(Trail1, Trail2)
    Sell = ta.crossunder(Trail1, Trail2)
    iff_3 = Trail2 > Trail1 ? -1 : 0
    SR = Trail1 > Trail2 ? 1 : iff_3

    if Buy and window() 
        strategy.entry("3", strategy.long, alert_message = "Buy będzie profit")

    else if Sell and window() 
        strategy.close("3", "Sell" )

    if barstate.islast or barstate.isrealtime
        netProfit := strategy.netprofit
        totalTrades := strategy.closedtrades
        profitableTrades := strategy.wintrades
        if totalTrades > 0
            profitFactor := strategy.netprofit / (totalTrades - profitableTrades)
            array.set(netProfitArray,per-3, netProfit)
            array.set(totalTradesArray, per-3, totalTrades)
            array.set(profitableTradesArray,per-3, profitableTrades)
            array.set(profitFactorArray, per-3, profitFactor)    
            array.set(iteracjaArray, per-3, per)    

if barstate.islast or barstate.isrealtime
    for i = 3 to 37
        table.cell(table, 0, i-2, str.tostring(array.get(netProfitArray,i-3)))
        table.cell(table, 1, i-2, str.tostring(array.get(totalTradesArray,i-3)))
        table.cell(table, 2, i-2, str.tostring(array.get(profitableTradesArray,i-3)))
        table.cell(table, 3, i-2, str.tostring(array.get(profitFactorArray,i-3)))
        table.cell(table, 4, i-2, str.tostring(mova))
        table.cell(table, 5, i-2, str.tostring(array.get(iteracjaArray,i-3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript, you can only have one strategy at a time.

strategy.netprofit value is global, and for for all trades and all your variation of your strategy.
So when you loop with per 3 to 37, and when you look on the last bar only to record your netprofit, you will always record the same value.
You have to create your own calculation about the result of your strategies and store them independently to be able to loop in and record each result for each variation of the strategy.